# Help me install Ubuntu 18.04 (No root file system is defined error):

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, mbr

I want to install Ubuntu alongside Windows 10. I use Legacy BIOS partitioning and my disk partitions are MBR.

/sda1 NTFS Primary Boot Windows 10 104 GB total  33 GB used  71 GB free
/sda2 NTFS Primary 104,279 GB total unknown used/free
/sda3 NTFS Primary 471 GB total 412 GB used  59GB free
/sda4 NTFS Primary 363,790 GB total 222,285 GB used 141,505 GB free
unusable 31,459 GB

I downloaded Ubuntu 18.04 and put it on a usb flash drive using Rufus. I also created 30 GB free space for Ubuntu.

However, when I'm trying to install the Ubuntu, when I'm selecting the free space, the change function can't be accessed, and when I try to install, it says "No root file system is defined. Please correct this from the partitioning menu". Would be really great if someone can help me figure this out. [screenshot_1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yi2KH.png)  [screenshot_2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8FBLB.png)

Comment: The free space is unusable because you already have the maximum number of primary partitions allowed. That's the problem with MBR.

Comment: What are /sda2 /sda3 and /sda4 used for? Please click [edit] and answer in the original question. Please do not use Add Comment, please click [edit]. I will propose one of those be consolidated with its neighbor, deleted, and then you create an extended partition, in which you can make more logical partitions. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/configure-more-than-four-partitions-on-a-biosmbr-based-hard-disk